# System.Text.Json Error Handling equivalency to Newtonsoft.Json (json.net) JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, system.text.json

We are following in .Net Core's path in transitioning from Newtonsoft.Json to the new System.Text.Json.  One feature of Newtonsoft that we found convenient was to provide an error handler in the JsonSerializerSettings to log details which has greatly facilitated identifying and fixing serialization problems.  As such:

```
jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
        logger.LogDebug($"JSON Parsing Error. Type={args.CurrentObject} Member={args.ErrorContext.Member} Path={args.ErrorContext.Path}  Error={args.ErrorContext.Error.Message}");
    }
};
```

Is anyone aware of an equivalent behavior that could be configured for System.Text.Json?

Comment: Doesn't look that way, see [System.Text.Json support a way to ignore/handle exceptions on serialization #44390](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44390).  Plus there's no mention of error handling in [How to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).  `System.Text.Json` does give fairly useful error messages though, including the precise location (line number, byte position + JSONPath) in the JSON stream where the exception was thrown.